# show only the content of article

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

how do I only show content in a single article?

I am using Joomla 2.5 and Ajax to call a single article, but when I render the article in a `<div>` tag,  I render again the header, the footer and all the page , but I only want the content.

How do I configure the page or the article to show only the content?

Comment: Hard to say without looking at any of the code you have used. Please provide more details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you only want to get component you can append `tmpl=component` parameter with the url.
Your article url will be like this-

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1&tmpl=component
```

Or you can try like this-

```
$('#result').load('index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1&tmpl=component #container');
```

[Loading Page Fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)