# How to put a Joomla 2.5 backend view in a modal window

Tags: view, joomla, components, modal-dialog, backend

i like to open a components backend view in a modal window. All my attempts lead me to a modal window displaying the whole backend in an iframe in the modal window. I used this link to open the window:

```
<?php 
$link = 'index.php?option=com_serveradmin&view=filehistory&layout=modal&id=' . (int)$file->id;
?>
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_($link);?>" class="modal"
rel="{handler: 'ajax', size: {x: 875, y: 550}, onClose: function() {}}" >
<?php echo $file->orig_name; ?>
</a>
```

the view folder contains the modal.php with this code:

```
    defined('_JEXEC') or die;
    JHtml::_('behavior.modal');
    ?>

<h1>This is the file history</h1>
```

and nothing more and this is all I like to display for the first step.
Anyone tried this before? Is there a way to accomplish that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add tmpl=component in your url.more details are here-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275611/show-only-the-content-of-article/13283708#13283708

Answer (score 0):

You can add `tmpl=component` to your url, so Joomla will only rendering the compontent without the template. In fact Joomla will using the `component.php` from your current template.