# Joomla Ajax call component layout

Tags: ajax, search, joomla, filter, k2

I'm developing k2 extra-field ajax filter search here I completed every thing but in my search the ajax response bring the whole page I only want to display the k2 filter result only.

**The problem I facing**

1. On click submit the ajax response load full html
2. Due to full load of html the data entered in the filter form was lost.

**I'm using these kind of url to retrieve the result.**

1. ?option=com_k2&controller=itemlist&layout=category
2. index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category

I want to load only k2 list view.

Comment: this might be helpful to you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275611/show-only-the-content-of-article/13283708#13283708

Comment: Thank you its finally worked "index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&tmpl=component"

Comment: Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you to ask your future [tag:joomla] questions there.